# Equivalence of Hermitian operator and Hermitian matrix in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation

I learned that a Hermitian matrix $A$ is defined as a matrix that satisfies
$$A^\dagger=(A^*)^\intercal=A,$$
i.e. its Hermitian conjugate $A^\dagger$ is the same as the original matrix $A$.

I also learned that in QM, a Hermitian operator $H$ is defined as an operator that satisfies
$$ \langle f|Hg\rangle=\langle Hf|g\rangle,$$
where $f$ and $g$ are vectors.

Since operators and matrix can be represented by matrices in a particular basis, how can it be shown that a Hermitian matrix with the property $(A^*)^\intercal=A$ also satisfies $ \langle f|Ag\rangle=\langle Af|g\rangle$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\langle f|Ag\rangle=\langle f|A|g\rangle$.

$\langle Af|g\rangle$:

- $(\langle Af|) = (|Af\rangle)^\dagger =(A|f\rangle)^\dagger = \langle f |A^\dagger$,
- so $\langle Af|g\rangle = \langle f |A^\dagger|g\rangle$

If $A = A^\dagger$, then $\langle f|Ag\rangle  =\langle Af|g\rangle$.

Comment: in infinite dimensional spaces there are subtleties of domain etc...

Comment: Hi :-) I think that there is a missing symbol here: $\langle f |A^\dagger$ into your answer. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

In matrix form,
$$\langle f|Ag\rangle = f^\dagger A g,$$
$$\langle Af|g\rangle= (Af)^\dagger g.$$

Using the matrix property of $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$ on the latter expression, we get
$$\langle Af|g\rangle = (Af)^\dagger g=f^\dagger A^\dagger g.$$

Hence if $A=A^\dagger$, then $$\langle Af|g\rangle= f^\dagger A^\dagger g= f^\dagger A g=\langle f|Ag\rangle.$$